# how do I get a random number inside of json

Tags: json, random, swagger-ui

I'm trying to make an api so I'm using the Swagger UI thing and I'm trying to make a document return something like this

```json
{
"link":"https://example.com/images/image" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (4-1)+1) + ".png"
}
```

How would I do this, because if I do this I get this error

{
"description": "Malformed JSON object found during read: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('+' (code 43)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (String)"{\n"link":"https://example.com/images/image" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (4-1)+1) + ".png"\n}"; line: 2, column: 44]",
"code": 400
}

(I'm new to the site so the post isn't that good)
Thanks

Comment: You can only execute JavaScript code in a JavaScript file (ending in .js).

Comment: ok, but is there a way to do what I said in swagger ui, in a different way?

Comment: Basically, "no". You must use app/script code to execute the code fragment and put its result into the json.

Comment: ok thanks(filler text)